# Testing timeout-related tests, such as Popups/Tooltips etc with Detox

Tags: ios, automated-tests, detox

I've beed using `detox` for a while, but after upgrade to `17.5.+` I have started facing an issue with Popups testing. I haven't find useful info on a stack overflow and on detox issues.

Problem here is the following: I have a test to check if correct popup is shown. It looks like:

```
it('expect to see "Answer correct" popup', async () => {
  await openQuestionnaire('theory_questionnaire_learn_button');

  await scroll('questionnaire_scroll_view', 150);

  await element(by.id('select_1_button')).tap();

  await element(by.id('questionnaire_answer_button')).tap();

  // @ts-ignore
  await expect(element(by.id('questionnaire_simple_popup'))).toBeVisible();
  // @ts-ignore
  await expect(element(by.id('questionnaire_simple_popup'))).toHaveLabel('correct');

  await delay(500);

  // @ts-ignore
  await expect(element(by.id('questionnaire_simple_popup'))).toNotExist();
});
```

Background for this: after questionnaire_answer_button is tapped, popup appears. It is visible for 500ms and then it disappears. For this 500ms I'm using `setTimeout({ () => dismiss() }, 500)`.

Popup is visible on an emulator, but my test fails with `Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(identifier: == “questionnaire_simple_popup”)”`

Checking hierarchy I haven't find this element there. Maybe someone else have already faced this and know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what have I found out after several tries. It start working after increasing timeout from 500ms to 3000ms. 2500 was still failing, 2750 haven't tried. Regarding matchers. `by.id` and `by.text` works as well.

So the reason probably was a timeout duration.

Answer (score 0):

If the identifier is not found, it means the identifier has not been properly set with the native view’s accessibility identifier. Check with the popup developer that testID are properly forwarded to the native views.

Comment: I haven't changed the identifier and the related code at all. But as I said, after update to 17.+.+ it is never visible. Sometimes it works if `await` is removed from `await expect(element(by.id('questionnaire_simple_popup'))).toBeVisible();`. But it's not the solution

Comment: Your failure is not about visibility, but matching. You are attempting to match a view that doesn't exist at the time of matching. This could mean synchronization is somehow broken, but synchronization has not changed in Detox 17.

Comment: You say that it is visible when matching occurs. That means the identifier is not found in the view hierarchy.

Comment: isn't it a common problem? Probably I do something wrong, but it looks like common test. Regarding what have you commented initially: 

`<View accessible testID={\`${testID}_simple_popup\`} accessibilityLabel={isCorrect ? 'correct' : 'wrong'}>...`

Which means that test ID matches native View. Here is the test ID which could not match. I've been checking it and even hardcoded it to be `questionnaire_simple_popup` but test still fails

Comment: Try matching by label or text. It’s not common that testIDs cannot be matched, so I’m not sure what is going on. Pause your app in Xcode and use the view hierarchy inspector to look for your view. See if it has the accessibility identifier. If it doesn’t, your app is broken.

Comment: it is accessibility element. It presents in the View Hierarchy. I will try to increase timeout